# SQLite Browser "Error checking foreign keys after table modification. The changes will be reverted."

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with tables `albums` and `songs` as follows:

Albums:
[image: albums table]

Songs:
[image: songs table]

I want to make the tables related, wtih `albums` being the parent and `songs` being the child, so I tried to turn the albumsId column in `songs` into a foreign key
[image]
But it always gives me the aforementioned "Error checking foreign keys after table modification". I have a couple of testing entries in both tables, could this be the case?

Comment: Drop and recreate the table Songs with the foreign key constraint.

Comment: So you can't assign foreign keys in the table that has been initialized already?

Comment: You can't make an existing column as foreign key.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to `Edit Pragmas` and uncheck the `Foreign keys` option then the database will stop checking foreign key constraints. This will allow you to add the foreign key constraint without generating an error – you can then turn the foreign key pragma back on to enable checking for any future modifications (e.g. row insertion).

If you do this you still need to check that the foreign key constraint is satisfied for your existing table/data. To do this, select `Tools` > `Foreign-Key Check`. This will generate a table showing any foreign key violations, which you should fix if you can.